# How do I merge different Dataframes and label each dataframe in the merged dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

lets say for example we have 2 Dataframes, df1 and df2;

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A01', 'A02'],
                    'Name': ['ABC', 'PQR']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['B05', 'B06'],
                    'Name': ['XYZ', 'TUV']})
```

I want to merge the two and label each dataframes, so it appears like this.

[image: enter image dwescription here]

So basically, i want to concatenate two dataframes into a new dataframe and create a third column that labels each of those dataframes. As seen the the table above, you can see that there is a 3rd column named 'class' and the values there are grouping of each dataframes that were merged. The first two above are data for df1 and it was labelled as 1 for all of them. it groups all of them and put them as one.

i'm trying to make sure it doesn't appear like this one below;
[image]

in this case, it's appending for each line.. i prefer to append to the whole DF as single entity as shown in the first table.

This is what I have tried;

```
 df1['class'] = 1
 df2['class'] = 2

 df_merge = pd.concat([df1,df2])
```

and i got result like this
[image]

But this is not what I was expecting. I am expecting the result to look like this. Grouping each df as one and add the 3rd column.
[image]

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect what i was trying to illustrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) using the `keys` and `names` parameters, then [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
(pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=[1, 2], names=['class', None])
   .reset_index('class')
)
```

Output:

```
   class   id Name
0      1  A01  ABC
1      1  A02  PQR
0      2  B05  XYZ
1      2  B06  TUV
```

Or without `reset_index` to get a MultiIndex:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=[1, 2], names=['class', None])

          id Name
class            
1     0  A01  ABC
      1  A02  PQR
2     0  B05  XYZ
      1  B06  TUV
```

##### hiding the "duplicated" class:

```
(pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=[1, 2], names=['class', None])
   .reset_index('class')
      .assign(**{'class': lambda d: d['class'].mask(d['class'].duplicated(), '')})
)
```

Output:

```
  class   id Name
0     1  A01  ABC
1        A02  PQR
0     2  B05  XYZ
1        B06  TUV
```

Comment: Thanks alot. This looks like that i'm expecting. But i wasn't able to use the 'class' column just incase i want to use the 'class' column in filtering

Comment: @Thomas I added an example to hide the duplicated class, but know that this is bad practice! this will prevent you from using the column in a meaningful way.

Comment: oh nice. I see your point. So basically, it's not possible to group each dataframes as single entity? for example, the first two rows in your final table, can it be labelled as class 1 and the last two as class two? and to be able to run query to filter by class 1?

Comment: No it's not. "merging" cells does not exist in pandas. There is only a cosmetic merging of successive values in a MultiIndex when displayed (see my second example)